# A Regular Expression that I know is correct, doesn't work with awk. Please advise

Tags: regex, shell, awk

Following up on an answer by [@dawg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298607/dawg) to my question how to delete multiple sections in a file based on known patterns, I want to use a regular expression in awk to identify the start of the section(s) I want to delete.
The file I am working with is an xml file. It is in fact the file containing the recently used filenames list (RUFL) in Linux Mint (~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel).
This is how the RUFL is structured:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xbel version="1.0"
      xmlns:bookmark="http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/desktop-bookmarks"
      xmlns:mime="http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info"
>
  <bookmark href="file:///home/ocor61/Documents/Linux/Linux%20Mint%20Cinnamon%20Keyboard%20Shortcuts.pdf" added="2021-07-18T01:57:02Z" modified="2021-07-18T01:57:02Z" visited="1969-12-31T23:59:59Z">
    <info>
      <metadata owner="http://freedesktop.org">
        <mime:mime-type type="application/pdf"/>
        <bookmark:applications>
          <bookmark:application name="Document Viewer" exec="&apos;xreader %u&apos;" modified="2021-07-18T01:57:02Z" count="1"/>
        </bookmark:applications>
      </metadata>
    </info>
  </bookmark>
  <bookmark href="file:///home/ocor61/Documents/Linux/Linux%20Command%20Line%20Cheat%20Sheet.pdf" added="2021-07-18T01:57:09Z" modified="2021-07-18T01:57:09Z" visited="1969-12-31T23:59:59Z">
    <info>
      <metadata owner="http://freedesktop.org">
        <mime:mime-type type="application/pdf"/>
        <bookmark:applications>
          <bookmark:application name="Document Viewer" exec="&apos;xreader %u&apos;" modified="2021-07-18T01:57:09Z" count="1"/>
        </bookmark:applications>
      </metadata>
    </info>
  </bookmark>
  <bookmark href="file:///home/ocor61/Documents/work.bfproject" added="2021-07-20T10:52:59Z" modified="2021-07-22T08:41:57Z" visited="1969-12-31T23:59:59Z">
    <info>
      <metadata owner="http://freedesktop.org">
        <mime:mime-type type="application/x-bluefish-project"/>
        <bookmark:applications>
          <bookmark:application name="bluefish" exec="&apos;bluefish %u&apos;" modified="2021-07-22T08:41:57Z" count="2"/>
        </bookmark:applications>
      </metadata>
    </info>
  </bookmark>
</xbel>
```

I am working on a script to remove filenames from the list. It works fine, but I am also working with an array that contains patterns that should not be used. For example: if the pattern [bookmark] would be used to identify a section that must be removed, the entire file would become unusable. That goes for parts of [bookmark], but also for href, added, info... You get my drift.

So, I want to work with a regexp to counter the problems of entering patterns that cannot be used.

Currently, this is the awk code I am using now (thanks to @dawg):

```
ENDLINE='</bookmark>'    
awk -v f=1 -v st="$1" -v end="$ENDLINE" '
match($0, st) {f=0}
f
match($0, end){f=1}' ~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel
```

$1 would be the pattern a user enters at the command line, which is part of the file name that must be removed from the RUFL.

The following is the code I would like to use, including the regexp, which doesn't work:

```
STARTLINE='/(<bookmark href)(.*)($1)(.*)(>)/'
ENDLINE='</bookmark>'
awk -v f=1 -v st="$STARTLINE" -v end="$ENDLINE" '
match($0, st) {f=0}
f
match($0, end){f=1}' ~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel
```

I have tested the regular expression at https://regexr.com/, so I know it is correct. However, when I use it in my script, this is the error message I am getting:

```
./ruffle.sh: line 99: syntax error near unexpected token `$0,'
./ruffle.sh: line 99: `      match($0, st) {f=0}'
```

I have also tried to enter the regexp itself in the awk command line instead of the variable, but that has the same result.

I don't know how to proceed, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps not likely here, but don't expect `awk` regex to match those implemented in languages like JS, there are various differences. Potential issues in your attempt 1) variables are not expanded within single quotes in shells like `bash` 2) When you pass a string to be used as a regexp, you shouldn't use `//` delimiters. Also, I'd suggest to use a `xml` parser instead of `awk`

Comment: Testing a regexp on https://regexr.com/ or an other online tool just proves it works in that tool, it doesn't mean it'll work in any given command-line tool. Also, `/` is the regexp delimiter, it's not part of the regexp. Including `/` in a regexp is like including `"` in a string. Having said that - nothing in your awk script would produce the error message you say it does, it's probably a bug in the calling code. Please create and post a [mcve] that can reproduce your problem (I expect by creating the minimal example you'll figure out the answer for yourself though).

Comment: Copy/paste your full shell script into http://shellcheck.net and it'll probably tell you what the problem is.

Comment: Thank you both, @Sundeep and @EdMorton! It now works like a charm. I'll answer my own question with the solution I found.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question lies in how regular expressions can differ when used in different environments. The website I used to check my regexp does so for languages like JS, but not for Bash or likely other shell implementations.
With shellcheck.net as well as by putting the command 'set -vx' in my script right before the awk command, I managed to work things out.

Another mistake I made was to attempt to catch the complete line in the regexp, while I need only the part in that line that can hold the pattern that is entered (which is the part between 'file:' and 'added' in the file ~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel).

The regexp that ultimately works for me now with the variable STARTLINE is:

```
STARTLINE='file:.*'$1'.*added='
```

I will have to look into using an xml parser, thanks for the suggestion! For now, however, my script works. Thanks @Sundeep and @EdMorton!